# convert dict of dict into a dataframe

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a slightly complicated json that I need to convert into a dataframe. This is a standard output json from another API and hence the field names will not change.

I have the below dict which is more complicated than what I have worked with till now

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data = [{'annotation_spec': {'description': 'Story_Driven',
...    'display_name': 'Story_Driven'},
...   'segments': [{'confidence': 0.52302074,
...     'segment': {'end_time_offset': {'nanos': 973306000, 'seconds': 14},
...      'start_time_offset': {}}}]},
...  {'annotation_spec': {'description': 'real', 'display_name': 'real'},
...   'segments': [{'confidence': 0.5244379,
...     'segment': {'end_time_offset': {'nanos': 973306000, 'seconds': 14},
...      'start_time_offset': {}}}]}]
```

I looked through all related SO posts and the closest I can get this into a dataframe is this

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_normalize(data,record_path= 
['segments'],meta=[['annotation_spec','description'], 
['annotation_spec','display_name']],errors='ignore'))
```

This gives me an output like this

```
>>> from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
>>> pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_normalize(data,record_path=['segments'],meta=[['annotation_spec','description'],['annotation_spec','display_name']],errors='ignore'))
   confidence                                            segment annotation_spec.description annotation_spec.display_name
0    0.523021  {u'end_time_offset': {u'nanos': 973306000, u's...                Story_Driven                 Story_Driven
1    0.524438  {u'end_time_offset': {u'nanos': 973306000, u's...                        real                         real
>>>
```

I want to break down the "segment"column above as well into its components. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically `json_normalize` takes care of nested dicts, here we have a problem because of the list in the segements key.

So if the length of the list will always be 1, we can just remove the list and then apply `json_normalize`

```
### function to remove the lsit, we basically check if its a list, if so just take the first element
remove_list = lambda dct:{k:(v[0] if type(v)==list else v) for k,v in dct.items()}

data_clean = [remove_list(entry) for entry in data]

json_normalize(data_clean, sep="__")
```

[image]